# Storing output of GNU time command and script

Tags: python, linux, bash, gnu

I am trying to `tee` the output of a Python script so that I can watch its progress and record its output.  However, I am also pre-pending the `/usr/bin/time` command so that I can measure memory overhead and timing as well.

When I run the command as follows I only see the output of the Python script, not of the `/usr/bin/time` command.

`(/usr/bin/time -f '%P %M %E %S %U' python Script.py arg1 arg2) | tee Script.output`

When I run it as follows, (naturally) I don't see the output on the terminal, however I get the correct output (i.e., the output of the script followed by the memory/timing overhead).

`(/usr/bin/time -f '%P %M %E %S %U' python Script.py arg1 arg2) &> Script.output`

Is there a way to incorporate `tee` in here?  I would much prefer to see its progress, as this script can take a day or two to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time` command writes its output to `stderr`, so as to not pollute the `stdout` of the process being timed.

Notice that in your second example, you're redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` with `&>`.

If you want to also pipe `stderr` to `tee`, use `|&`:

```
(/usr/bin/time -f '%P %M %E %S %U' python Script.py arg1 arg2) |& tee Script.output
```